# Question about proof for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am attempting to prove the following statement (Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma) and have a few questions regarding the proof:

> For $f\in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R}),$ show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$$

I recently showed that the simple functions are dense in $\mathcal{L}^{p}(\Bbb{R})$, so I figured i'd use this in proving this lemma. Here is a proof I have been working on using that information.

Let $\Phi \subset \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ be the subset of all simple functions of $\mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$. Since $\Phi$ is dense in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $f \in\mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ there is some $\phi \in \Phi$ such that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|\phi-f| \leq \epsilon$. Therefore $$\left|\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\right| \leq \int_{\Bbb{R}}|\phi-f|+\left|\int_{\Bbb{R}}\phi(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\right|\leq \epsilon + \left|\int_{\Bbb{R}}\phi(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\right|.$$

Since $$\limsup_{|n| \to +\infty}\left|\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)\cos{(nx)}\,dx\right| \leq \epsilon+0=\epsilon \label{a}\tag{1}$$ and $\epsilon >0$
is arbitrary we have that $\displaystyle\limsup_{|n| \to +\infty}\left|\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)\cos{(nx)}\,dx\right| = 0.$ So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0.\quad_{\Box}$$

**My question is:**

How do we know that in $(1)$ the $\displaystyle\limsup_{|n| \to +\infty} \left|\int_{\Bbb{R}}\phi(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\right| = 0$ and why are we taking the $\displaystyle\limsup_{|n| \to +\infty}$ of $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$ to show $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$?

Comment: a simple function $\phi$ is constant on an interval and when you integrate it against $\cos(nx)dx$, you get $\dfrac{C\sin(nx)}{n}\to 0.$ As for your second question, if $|\lim\sup a_n| = 0$, then $\lim a_n = 0,$ very obviously because of the absolute value.

Comment: @dezdichado - gotcha, my only question is why can we consider the simple function over an interval when the integral is over all of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: You should read the definitions again - a simple function is a finite linear combination of indicator functions, so there is a finitely many number of intervals to consider.

Comment: @dezdichado - Gotcha. Also, I believe the person who originally posted an answer for this question deleted their answer and down voted this post on the way out. If you think this post is fair, would you mind voting as well? :-) If not, thank you for your time in answering my questions, your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sure - just did. In general, it's bad practice to leave a question unanswered here so you should write a nice answer and accept it yourself so it's useful for future users.